# Pascal division without remainder

Tags: pascal, division

Write a program that will return 1 if m divides on n without remainder and 0 if not.

```
program Division;
var m, n:longint;
begin
   readln(m, n);  
   writeln(5 mod 4);
   writeln((1-(n mod m)div 2));
end.
```

Comment: `Writeln(Ord(n mod m = 0))` or `if n mod m = 0 then Writeln(1) else Writeln(0)`

Answer (score -1):

```
program Division;
var n, m: integer;
begin
    readln(n,m);
    writeln (1 - (n mod m + 1) div 2 mod 2);
end.
```